# Django get all related Choices where Event=Event.id

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to create my first application using Django. I'm using the following code to create a list of events.

```
{% for Event in location_list %}                         
{{ Event.lat }}, {{ Event.long }},
html: "{{ Event.id }}",
}]
{% endfor %}
```

I need to edit the code so that

```
{{ Event.id }}
```

Becomes something like

```
{{ Get all Choice in choice_list WHERE event IS Event.id }}
```

What is the proper syntax for doing this?

## Model.py

```
from django.db import models

class Event(models.Model):
    info = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    long = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    lat = models.CharField(max_length=200)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.info

class Choice(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=200)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.choice
```

## views.py

```
def index(request):
location_list = Event.objects.all()
choice_list = Choice.objects.all()
t = loader.get_template('map/index.html')
c = Context({
            'location_list': location_list,
            'choice_list': choice_list,
            })
return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

## Update

I have replaced

```
{{ Event.id }}
```

with

```
{% for choice in event.choice_set.all %} {{ choice }} {% endfor %}
```

It doesn't print any events.

Comment: To avoid confusion between the `Event` model and individual `event`s, it's good style to use lowercase variable names for your event objects i.e. `{% for event in location_list %}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to [follow relationships backward](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).

```
# In the shell
# fetch events from the db
>>> events = Event.objects.all()
>>> for event in events:
...     # fetch all the choices for this event
...     event_choices = event.choice_set.all() 
...     print event_choices
```

In the template, you don't include the parenthesis for the method call.

```
{% for event in location_list %}                         
  {{ event.lat }}, {{ event.long }}
  <ul>
    {% for choice in event.choice_set.all %}
      <li>{{ choice }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

You may want to define the `related_name` parameter in your foreign key definition:

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, related_name="choices")
```

Then you can use `event.choices.all()` in your views and `{% for choice in event.choices.all %}` in your templates.

Comment: Why would I define event as Event.objects.get(id=1). When event(id=1) is only 1 of many events in location_list.

Comment: Good question. I didn't mean that you should fetch `event=Event.objects.get(id=1)` in your view -- I was just defining an event so that I could show how to get its choices. I've edited the answer, hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: I see I'm using the {% for choice in choice_list %} {{ choice }} {% endfor %} code now but not sure how to define 'event' so it works for each 'event in location list'. I've updated my question to include my views.py

Comment: Try the template snippet in my answer {% for choice in event.choice_set.all %}. Unless you want to filter the list of choices, you don't need to include choice_list in your view.

Comment: I have tried adding the snippet of code with the {% for choice in event.choice_set.all %} but I get no results printed.

Comment: My snippet should work. What output do you get if you try my snippet to print the event_choices for each event?

Comment: Apologize it was an error in how I copied it into what I was doing.